# how to create a slideshow using Theme Options in wordpress by getting the Images user dynamically?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have actually created the wordpress theme and now I want to implement dynamic slideshow options in my page by getting the values dynamically from the user using the theme options from wordpress dashboard.

Please any one help me, but don't recommend any plugins. I need only code to upload many Images as my Image count increases.

Comment: you want to create a slide show based on the images supplied by the cms? or you want the images to come from the user?

Answer (score 0):

This could potentially be done on the post system, that is, if I'm understanding what you seek to do.

You could allow users to have post privileges limited to images and use the featured post functionality with images.

To do this from the theme options, you could port the posting mechanism to theme options, as I don't see a way to rig this with the native theme options (unless you were to allow user uploaded themes, which a bad idea).